# Count total number of duplicate rows in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL for inspecting duplicate rows in a table that has the following columns: `id`, `case_id`, `raw_name`, `initials`, `name`, `judge_id`, `magistrate_id` and `score`.

```
SELECT MIN(id), case_id, initials, raw_name, count(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY case_id, raw_name, initials, name, judge_id, magistrate_id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

(A row is considered duplicate if it contains the same values in the `case_id`, `raw_name`, `initials`, `name`, `judge_id` and `magistrate_id` columns.)

How can get the total number of duplicate rows that need to be deleted (leaving 1 row remaining for each set of duplicates)?

Comment: Are you sure you need all those columns in the GROUP BY? The common way is to list the same columns as selected (but not arguments to set functions), i.e. case_id, initials, and raw_name.

Comment: The columns in the GROUP BY are the ones that should match in order to be considered duplicates, at least that's my understanding. The columns in the SELECT are just the ones I happen to want to look at.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, if you know what you're doing. (But it's a common mistake to list too few or too many columns in the group by clause.)

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate problems can often be expressed in terms of `EXISTS(the other)`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table mt
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM my_table x
        WHERE x.case_id = mt.case_id -- exactly the same "keys"
        AND x.raw_name = mt.raw_name
        AND x.initials = mt.initials
        AND x.name = mt.name
        AND x.judge_id = mt.judge_id
        AND x.magistrate_id = mt.magistrate_id
        AND x.id < mt.id             -- but a smaller (surrogate) key
          -- If your table doesn't have a unique (surrogate) key,
          -- you can use the internal "ctid" which is guaranteed to be unique
          -- AND x.ctid < mt.ctid
        );
```

For your final delete query: just replace the `SELECT COUNT(*)` by `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

`select count(distinct column_name) from`

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
SELECT MIN(id), case_id, initials, raw_name, count(*)-1
FROM my_table GROUP BY case_id, raw_name, initials,
name, judge_id, magistrate_id HAVING count(case_id) > 1 and 
count(raw_name) > 1 and  count(initials) > 1 and  count(name) > 1 and
count(judge_id) > 1 and count(magistrate_id ) > 1 ;
```

[Sample DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e5c66/11) its Just a Sample

Comment: `count(*)-1` doesn't appear to be valid SQL. Also, I'm looking for the total count, not the count for each set of duplicates.